# How to make a simple encoder and decoder?

Tags: javascript, chat, encoder, decoder

I have the following code:

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Chat Encoder
//Made by Hducke aka Hunter Ducker

//VARS
var userInputA = "";
var userInputB = "";
var result = userInputB.split("");

//FUNCTIONS

var encodeMessage = function(){

    var output = "";

    userInputB = prompt("Type your message here:", "PLEASE TYPE YOUR MESSAGE IN LOWER CASE!");

    for(var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++){
        switch(result[i]){
            case("a"):
                result[i] = "1";
            break;
            case("b"):
                result[i] = "2";
            break;
            case("c"):
                result[i] = "3";
            break;
        }

          var tempStr = "";

           result[i] + tempStr;

    }

    return tempStr;

}

var decodeMessage = function(){

}

var promptUser = function(){

    var tempBool = true;

    while(tempBool){
    userInputA = prompt("Type '1' to encode a message and '2' to decode a message!", "Type '1' or '2' here.");

    switch(userInputA){
        case("1"):
            encodeMessage();
            tempBool = false;
        break;
        case("2"):
            decodeMessage();
            tempBool = false;
        break;
        default:
            alert("Try again. Please type a '1' or a '2'.");
    }

    }
}

var printMessage = function(){
    alert(encodeMessage);
}

//LOGIC
promptUser();
printMessage();

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Info: The way it is atm is it takes in the users input `userInputB` and parses it into separate characters. Then it sets the characters to a different character (scambles the character). Then it outputs the string to the user. My goal is to have it to where you can enter a message `I love this website!` and turn it into `1 2324 5654 7503947`. Then another user can enter the encoded message and the `decodeMessage` function will decode the message and output it to the user.

First issue: It won't currently work as is.*

*EDIT: Now when I run the code after fixing the `result[i]`.
[Output I Get Now](http://pastebin.com/Gfi4ASYP)

Second issue: How can I do this (IE. Is there a better way of doing this)

Any tips can help. I'm kinda a noob at javascript. Thanks!

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit vague. To help you along: "I can (...), but when I (...), (nothing happens / something unexpected happens)"

Comment: When I enter '1' in the prompt (for the encoder section of the program) it takes me to the encoder prompt where I enter a message. I click ok and then nothing happens. ATM 'a' 'b' and 'c' are the only letter that can be encoded. Also, the decoder section hasn't been made yet.

Comment: It looks like you have some syntax errors. Where you have `result(i)` you should be using `result[i]`. Parentheses call a function, while brackets get a property.

Comment: I fixed all of the errors, but now it outputs code.

`function(){

 var outputStr = "";

 userInputB = prompt("Type your message here:", "PLEASE TYPE YOUR MESSAGE IN LOWER CASE!");
 
 for(var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++){
  switch(result[i]){
   case("a"):
    result[i] = "1";
   break;
   case("b"):
    result[i] = "2";
   break;
   case("c"):
    result[i] = "3";
   break;
  }
  
  result[i] + outputStr;
  
 }
 
 return outputStr;
 
}`

Comment: It's kind of hard to read code in a comment, so maybe it would be better to edit your original question with the new information. Some people put it in a new paragraph, prefaced with "EDIT: "

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I've updated the http://jsfiddle.net/ntyt4/5/ with a sample scenario of the encoding and decoding process.  It should give you enough to get started.

---

A simpler way would be to use a dictionary with keys and their translated values.  You could store this in an object literal as:

```
var translation = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": "A"    
};
```

I've included a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntyt4/1/) to show you an example.  Just change the textbox value to one value to see the translation.

One thing to keep in mind though is that you will have to add every single character that needs to be translated to the object literal.  For example "a" will not translate the upper case version "A" for you because it is a different character.

Comment: This works great, but how would you be able to input a whole line of text and translate that.

Comment: A mapping disctionary is a reasonable solution, although it's not simple to use the same map for the decoder.

Comment: For the whole line of text, you would just loop character by character and keep adding to an encoded string you return at the end.  As for the decoding dictionary, you could possibly have a function reverse the order into a new dictionary and decode back that way.  Brian, an ASCII table translation is also not a bad idea, which people tend to like to use when doing encoding like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is with your input; `result` is not going to be updated when the user enters the prompt.

```
function encodeMessage() {
    var output = '';

    userInputB = prompt(...);
    result = userInputB.split('');
    ...
}
```

The second problem is the encoding itself. Instead of using a giant `switch`, create an algorithm to perform the encoding. In your case, you have a simple 1:1 mapping of a character to a number, conveniently in the natural order.

Did you know that your computer stores those letters as numbers? `'a'` is 97, `'b'` is 98, etc. so you could simply subtract 96 from the character to get a=1, b=2, etc.

However, this poses a problem for your decoder once you reach `'j'`. "java" is going to be turned into "101221", and if you simply perform the reverse of your encoder on that, you'll end up with "a`abba".

One option would be to return to your encoding scheme and the [ASCII table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html). `'1'` is character 49; perhaps you could subtract 48 from your characters instead? `'a'` would then become `'1'` (not much different from `1`) and so on. `'j'` becomes `':'`, and if you encode "java" you get ":1F1".

Once you're doing that, the reverse of your encoding scheme will become your decoder. Iterate over the encoded string, and add 48 instead of subtracting it.

Comment: "a`abba" -- and who wants to turn a cup of java into [ABBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abba)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very well the javascript but you have three options:

**Mapping the chars with two Vector** 
If you want to include the simple characters you need 25(a-z)+25(A-Z)+9(0-9)=59 conversion.
You can do this with an algoritm that if found a letter in the first vector for example at index "6", take the value from the corrispondent position in the second vector.

Decoding is the same way, only take from second vector and convert it in the equivalent for the first vector.

**ASCII Table** 
The char letter '0' casted in integer is 48. 
From 48-57 you have the number, in the range 65-90 you have the Upper char and in the range 97-122 you have the lower char. If you try to subtrack for example two your text is encoded in a simple system.

**MD5 Algoritm**
You can use/create a function that generate the [md5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash of a text, for example "encoding" in md5 is "[84bea1f0fd2ce16f7e562a9f06ef03d3](http://md5decryption.com/)". If you want use an encript system for encript an area this is the better way.

Comment: While md5 is a compromised hashing function and there exist large rainbow tables for it, md5 is not a "reversible" function. For someone that wants encryption _and decrpytion_, md5 is a poor choice.